# Bootstrap jumbotron full height without navbar's height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

HTML:

```
<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>


<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid vertical-center">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-3">TITLE</h1>
        <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>Description text</p>
        <p class="lead">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-jumbotron" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

CSS:

```
.navbar{
    padding: 7px 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.jumbotron {
    background-image: url(http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/97/93/UE7u4i.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
}

.vertical-center {
    min-height: 100%;  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */
    min-height: 100vh; /* These two lines are counted as one :-)       */

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.btn-jumbotron{
    background-color: black;
    border-color: white;
}
```

I'm trying to have a jumbotron have full height of the browser's window, but without the height of the static navbar. I did get it to size of full viewport by using `height: min-height:100vh` amnd center it, but as you can see from the jsfiddle example I have a scrollbar present because of the navbar's height - `64px`.

How can I remove that?

https://jsfiddle.net/iDaniel19/12qxmkjt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use calc

```
.vertical-center {
min-height: 100%;  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */
min-height: 100vh; /* These two lines are counted as one :-)       */

min-height: calc(100% - 64px);  /*  */
min-height: calc(100vh - 64px); /* */

display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

}

Comment: Thank you. I tried using calc but without the first 2 lines. I'll have a look at how that works now.

Comment: first two line is for browsers which doesn't support calc. I'm so glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add to .navbar position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%; and padding-top:64px; to .jumbotron